# Scan for wifi networks in Android with location turned off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I am trying to get the wifi networks available doing this:

```
private WifiManager wifiManager;
private List<ScanResult> scanResults;

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
        scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        Log.d(TAG, "" + scanResults.size());
        for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
            Log.d(TAG, scanResult.SSID);
        }
    }
}

private class TaskScan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        wifiManager.startScan();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    try {
        (new TaskScan()).execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the size of the list scanResults is always 0 when the location is turned off.

Is there anyway of scanning the wifi networks without the location enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It is Android 6's security. It does not allow you to get the WIFI scan results without enabling location. However I've found a permission similar to this topic. The `PEERS_MAC_ADDRESS` is a permission that allows apps to get the scan result without turning location.

But unfortunately I did not succeed to get the scanresult after adding the permission.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get scanResults without turning on GPS on Android versions of Lollipop and above is to set your app's `targetSDKversion` to 21 or lower.